# Trouble loading jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having an incredibly difficult time figuring out how to include a jquery script in my html file. I keep getting an uncaught syntax error on the first line of the jquery file. The console points to the gibberish line "bookmark88D²~ýôÙ0’¹AÖ(±Users" which appears to be the beginning of my file path.

I know that this is not browser specific, as I'm having the same problem in both firefox and chrome. Additionally, I've checked the path, made sure that the link to the jquery script comes before the my javascript file, and tried multiple jquery versions. Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Show the code you are using

Comment: Can you confirm the page loads correctly without the jquery script line? I suspect there is a syntax error somewhere in your other code